# WSO2 generate and use custom error codes

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I have created and deployed a java service for wso2. I need to create a sequence in WSO2 that will do failover to another endpoint in case a certain fault response is given by the java service. I would like to use the endpoint features "suspendOnFailure" and "markForSuspension" for certain error codes but I did not find a way to throw a certain error code from the Java service.

Is there any way I can throw an error code in java that will be interpreted by the endpoint in order to mark it as "suspended for failure" for a certain period of time ?

I tried using a  makefault mediator, but I don't know how to throw an error with an error code from this(or other) mediator that can be interpreted later in "suspendOnFailure".

Below I tried to use the PGWFAULT service to always send a fault with an error code that will be interpreted by "suspendOnFailure". It doesn't work that way...

```
 <proxy name="CommandClientService" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true"
          trace="enable">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <endpoint name="FaultyOne">
            <address uri="http://localhost:8282/services/PGWFAULT">
               <suspendOnFailure>
                  <errorCodes>101500</errorCodes>
                  <initialDuration>1</initialDuration>
                  <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                  <maximumDuration>1</maximumDuration>
               </suspendOnFailure>
               <markForSuspension>
                  <errorCodes>101500</errorCodes>
                  <retriesBeforeSuspension>20</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                  <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
               </markForSuspension>
            </address>
         </endpoint>
         <faultSequence>
            <log level="full">
               <property name="text" value="Fault sequence activatesNOW"/>
               <property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            </log>
            <send>
               <endpoint key="errorProvider"/>
            </send>
         </faultSequence>
      </target>
   </proxy>


 <proxy name="PGWFAULT" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <endpoint key="Local"/>
         <outSequence>
            <makefault version="soap12">
               <code xmlns:soap12Env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                     value="soap12Env:Receiver"/>
               <reason value="101500"/>
               <node/>
               <role>asdcasdf</role>
               <detail>a fault to be taken into account</detail>
            </makefault>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
      </target>
   </proxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error codes referenced into endpoint definition for suspension are based on http error codes

You can set such an error code in your mediation like that :

```
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="500" scope="axis2"/>
```

For a list of error codes in Endpoint Error Handling, see http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Endpoint+Error+Handling

I think you will easily find how to set it in java...

For exemple on a HttpServletResponse object :

```
response.sendError(response.SC_NOT_FOUND, "No XXX specified.");
```